# Couldn't start project on Android: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I downloaded SDK into my D Drive so I have D:/AppData/Android/Sdk and it gave me the error of: Couldn't start project on Android: The system cannot find the path specified.

The environment variables is set to the same path in D Drive

Comment: What are the commands run to start the project? Are you trying to run it from Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I am, the command was the default: npm run android